# Rounding mysql dates to 2 day periods

Tags: mysql, date

I want to order my SQL statement by date and popularity score like this...

```
select *
from results
order by date(create_date) DESC, popularity DESC
```

The date function above removes the hours/minutes - so it orders by day, and most popular, but what I really want to achieve is to order based on 2 day windows.

Is there any way I can round dates into 48 hour periods?  Something like this...

```
2016-03-30 13:18:04 = 2016-03-30
2016-03-31 13:18:04 = 2016-03-30
2016-04-01 13:18:04 = 2016-04-01
2016-04-02 13:18:04 = 2016-04-01
```

Or perhaps I'm thinking about this wrong and there's a more sensible way to do it?!  Thanks for any thoughts at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can order by `year`, `month`, `day` separately, but just add a small calculation for `day`.

Try this:

```
select *
from results
order by 
    YEAR(create_date) DESC, 
    MONTH(create_date) DESC,
    FLOOR(DAY(create_date)/2.0) DESC,
    popularity DESC
```

Comment: @d3wannabe Note that odd days at the start and end of months won't be paired up here, the 1'st will be standalone, 2-3 will be paired, ... 28-29 will be paired, 30 will be standalone or paired with 31 if it exists etc. That may be what you want, however it's not quite a solution to your original question.

Answer (score 1):

Using unix timestamps, it's fairly easy to round to an arbitrary number of seconds (172800 here for 2 days);

```
SELECT *
FROM results
ORDER BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) DIV 172800 DESC, popularity DESC
```

[A quick SQLfiddle for testing](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/698c5/1).

Comment: this really works great too - has the added advantage that you don't have to worry about the "boundary" of a 2 day window.  Thanks Joachim